# Receiving JSON Data from a server and storing it in an array

Tags: json, react-native, api

I am creating a react native application with a tinder-like UI. Although instead of displaying users, it should display videogame covers. I have my nodejs server setup and I can receive information from it through postman.
Upon sending a get request to my server at http://localhost:9000/coverInfo,
I get this json as a response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 110592,
        "alpha_channel": false,
        "animated": false,
        "game": 96367,
        "height": 800,
        "image_id": "co2dc0",
        "url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co2dc0.jpg",
        "width": 800,
        "checksum": "04a45b3f-4f90-f4a1-cc0d-1483f0cc2612"
    },
    {
        "id": 65483,
        "game": 100547,
        "height": 800,
        "image_id": "pkkd08qhfxt5cosp3hra",
        "url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/pkkd08qhfxt5cosp3hra.jpg",
        "width": 1260,
        "checksum": "e09f916b-04fe-8993-594e-b18435438a35"
    },
    {
        "id": 96891,
        "alpha_channel": false,
        "animated": false,
        "game": 132099,
        "height": 933,
        "image_id": "co22rf",
        "url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co22rf.jpg",
        "width": 700,
        "checksum": "2452703f-4092-bb6f-d52c-51eb30a4ab94"
    },
....
```

From the client side, I am trying to retrieve this data and store it in an array. This is what my code looks like from the client side:

```
export default function App() {

   const [games, setGames] = useState([])
   const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
   const swipesRef = useRef(null)
   
   async function fetchGames() {
      try {
         const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/coverInfo')
         setGames(data.results)
         console.log(data.results)
     }   catch (error) {
         console.log
         Alert.alert('Error getting games', '', [{text: 'Retry', onPress: () => fetchGames()}])
   }
}


   useEffect(() => {
      fetchGames()
   }, [])

   function handleLike() {
      console.log('like')
      nextGame()
   }

   function handlePass() {
      console.log('pass')
      nextGame()
   }

   function nextGame() {
      const nextIndex = games.length - 2 == currentIndex ? 0 : currentIndex + 1
      setCurrentIndex(nextIndex)
   }

   function handleLikePress() {
      swipesRef.current.openLeft()
   }

   function handlePassPress(){
      swipesRef.current.openRight()
   }

   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <TopBar />
         <View style = {styles.swipes}>
            {games.length > 1 &&
               games.map(
                  (u, i) =>
                  currentIndex == i && (
                  <Swipes 
                     key = {i} 
                     ref={swipesRef} 
                     currentIndex={currentIndex} 
                     games={games} 
                     handleLike={handleLike} 
                     handlePass={handlePass}
                  ></Swipes>
                  )
               )}
         </View>
         <BottomBar handlePassPress={handlePassPress} handleLikePress={handleLikePress}/>
     </View>
   );
 }
```

However, I get the following error when running:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
App
C:/Users/matth/Joystik/App.js:62
  59 | return (
  60 |   <View style={styles.container}>
  61 |      <TopBar />
> 62 |       <View style = {styles.swipes}>
     | ^  63 |          {games.length > 1 &&
  64 |             games.map(
  65 |                (u, i) =>
View compiled
▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.
fetchGames$
C:/Users/matth/Joystik/App.js:23
  20 | async function fetchGames() {
  21 |    try {
  22 |       const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/coverInfo')
> 23 |       setGames(data.results)
     | ^  24 |       console.log(data.results)
  25 |   }   catch (error) {
  26 |       console.log
View compiled
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
```

The Code on my server side looks like this:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {

    axios({
        url: "https://api.igdb.com/v4/covers",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Client-ID' : '----------------------------',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ------------------',
        },
        data: "fields alpha_channel,animated,checksum,game,height,image_id,url,width;"
      })
      .then(response => {
        //console.log(response.data);
        const testing = response.data;
        res.json(testing);
        })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        });
    
    
});
```

I tried changing the "data.results" to just data but it doesn't work. The client is not getting anything from the node js server.

It can also be noted that I was able to successfully receive information from another client project that looked like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{

  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {apiResponse: ""};
  }

  callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/coverInfo")
    .then(res => res.text())
    //.then(res => console.log(res.json))
    .then(res => this.setState({apiResponse: res}));
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.callAPI();
  }

render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      </header>
      <p>
        {this.state.apiResponse}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

This returned the following text at the bottom of a webpage:

```
[{"id":110592,"alpha_channel":false,"animated":false,"game":96367,"height":800,"image_id":"co2dc0","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co2dc0.jpg","width":800,"checksum":"04a45b3f-4f90-f4a1-cc0d-1483f0cc2612"},{"id":65483,"game":100547,"height":800,"image_id":"pkkd08qhfxt5cosp3hra","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/pkkd08qhfxt5cosp3hra.jpg","width":1260,"checksum":"e09f916b-04fe-8993-594e-b18435438a35"},{"id":96891,"alpha_channel":false,"animated":false,"game":132099,"height":933,"image_id":"co22rf","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co22rf.jpg","width":700,"checksum":"2452703f-4092-bb6f-d52c-51eb30a4ab94"},{"id":9331,"game":8938,"height":750,"image_id":"ikjcylxero1pb1sl9clj","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/ikjcylxero1pb1sl9clj.jpg","width":640,"checksum":"0519ea95-feda-c674-1e6a-88a388ba5899"},{"id":900,"game":194,"height":362,"image_id":"fl0bjezupibkettkmsyg","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/fl0bjezupibkettkmsyg.jpg","width":300,"checksum":"ffbf4f5b-99b9-eab3-1eb6-ea7f4f9c2df1"},{"id":28001,"game":46426,"height":2156,"image_id":"arzwj3bju1aoakgufnku","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/arzwj3bju1aoakgufnku.jpg","width":1539,"checksum":"fb9fae9b-d717-d1d1-a3ee-ef6191af168d"},{"id":6424,"game":2410,"height":150,"image_id":"y7otr2cfclfpfuhtzhzq","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/y7otr2cfclfpfuhtzhzq.jpg","width":342,"checksum":"d41815d5-85a7-ac17-c067-ac88563578e9"},{"id":15242,"game":18896,"height":360,"image_id":"dq7tvq2dub1xj0jnqafe","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/dq7tvq2dub1xj0jnqafe.jpg","width":480,"checksum":"35bd8f63-6766-5426-d7c2-aaa34e8d8a19"},{"id":6432,"game":6264,"height":341,"image_id":"rii076tdl6uy1tnhohsg","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/rii076tdl6uy1tnhohsg.jpg","width":500,"checksum":"f48c9e58-b52f-382b-9d92-4031e5a5a15c"},{"id":27255,"game":48063,"height":2100,"image_id":"unmgn234f5uesld8nfcn","url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/unmgn234f5uesld8nfcn.jpg","width":1528,"checksum":"fec3c3a3-6edd-5a35-5440-f1a19455a9
```

Comment: Try like this :
{games?.length > 1 &&
               games.map(......

Comment: is.that `data.result` an array? or an object?

Comment: data.result should be an object

Comment: it seams  data.results is undefined. Please check data.results value before  passing it's value to setGames function.

Comment: What value you are getting in console.log(data.results) ? can you please share the exact value you are getting in the code?

Comment: The problem is the console doesn't log anything, I tested it with another api and it logged the json data. So I'm not sure why the client isn't receiving the data from my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be helpful to see your server side code if possible. cause seeing your
server response i think you should be just using `data` rather than `data.results` as your provided JSON is just data and has no other object (i might be wrong on the terminology here).

Because to use data.results you should have:

```
 {
        "results": [{
            "id": 110592,
            "alpha_channel": false,
            "animated": false,
            "game": 96367,
            "height": 800,
            "image_id": "co2dc0",
            "url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co2dc0.jpg",
            "width": 800,
            "checksum": "04a45b3f-4f90-f4a1-cc0d-1483f0cc2612"
        }, {
            "id": 65483,
            "game": 100547,
            "height": 800,
            "image_id": "pkkd08qhfxt5cosp3hra",
            "url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/pkkd08qhfxt5cosp3hra.jpg",
            "width": 1260,
            "checksum": "e09f916b-04fe-8993-594e-b18435438a35"
        }]
    }
```

And your comment specifying your console doesn't log anything gives me more confidence in my answer

Here is the code that you can use to use `data.results` (Under presumption that you are using nodeJS)

```
res.send({results: yourjsondata}).status(200)
```

And to avoid your app constantly crashing if you get no data (Good practice for production too).

```
        const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/coverInfo')
        if(data.results){
          setGames(data.results)
          console.log(data.results)
        }else{
          console.error("No data received from server")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I changed the catch block to the if statement and when running got this error:   [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError                                        I tried using just "data" instead of data.results but stull nothing.                                             The web console is saying "No data received from server"                                                     I included my server side code in the initial post

Comment: Could you provide the console log for the data you receive  server side ?

Comment: And the server side code you provided, is it actually the same route as your code has "/" route and the example you provided seems to be '/coverInfo' route according to your post

Comment: and the code example i provided to stop it from crashing you can change `games.length>1`  to just `games`

Comment: So when I console.log the server side, I get                                                                            [
  {
    id: 110592,
    alpha_channel: false,
    animated: false,
    game: 96367,
    height: 800,
    image_id: 'co2dc0',
    url: '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co2dc0.jpg',
    width: 800,
    checksum: '04a45b3f-4f90-f4a1-cc0d-1483f0cc2612'
},         (Basically the expected output)

Comment: For the router, I routed it through the proper file in app.js                                                      coverInfoRouter= require("./routes/coverInfo");                                                    app.use("/coverInfo", coverInfoRouter);                                                                I am able to make a successful request to http://localhost:9000/coverInfo on  postman so i dont think thats the issue

Comment: can you provide the response you get on postman, in cause you are modifying the data after you get it from the other api

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by not using localhost as the url because it was not loading on the android emulator.
The code that I used looked like this:

```
 async function fetchGames() {
         try {
            const {data} = await axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:9000/coverInfo')
            //console.log("ata", data)
            setGames(data)
         }  catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
            Alert.alert('Error getting users', '', [{text: 'Retry', onPress: () => fetchGames()}])
      }
   }
```